# Find non-identical text in two tables

Tags: vba, excel

**Problem:**
I am using Excel 2010 VBA to find non-identical (very long) Error Texts for an identical structure element (e.g. "123_789") and an identical Error Code (e.g. "ER005") between 2 tables. If the result is non-identical set the background color to yellow in the cell of the  first table.

It's like comparing two error protocols (new and old) to find out which errors texts for one error code and structure element are different.

One Error Code can be found for several structure elements. One Structure element can have several error codes but only one error code for one row.

Texts are variable.

**Example:**
Table1:

| StructureElement| ErrorCode| ErrorText|
|---------|-------|--------|
| 123_456 | ER001 | Text
| 123_789 | ER001 | Text
| 123_789 | ER005 | Textnew   <-this is the text cell to be colorized
| 123_456 | ER005 | Text1
| 123_456 | ER006 | Text

Table2:

| StructureElement| ErrorCode| ErrorText|
|---------|-------|--------|
| 123_456 | ER001 | Text
| 123_789 | ER001 | Text
| 123_789 | ER005 | Textold
| 123_456 | ER005 | Text1
| 123_456 | ER006 | Text

I'm concatenating the structure element with the Error Code and the Error Text to one big String for every table and writing it into table1. 
The Error Text itself can be very huge (that is why I'm comparing to find out differences).

Afterwards every cell of the new table1.Range1 is compared with the whole new table1.Range2 (from table2) and any mismatch is colorized.
The original Error Text in table1 is unfortunately not colorized.

Described as an Excel function it could be nearly

```
=IF(EXACT(A2&B2&E2;'Tab2'!A2&'Tab2'!B2&'Tab2'!E2);"";'Tab1'!$A$1)
```

But the term
1) " A2&B2&E2 " is in a loop for every row (for each...next)
2) " 'Tab2'!A2&'Tab2'!B2&'Tab2'!E2 " should be a range instead comparing equal rows
3) " "";'Tab1'!$A$1 " should colorize the background if you have no match otherwise do nothing

My unfinished VBA solution is up to now very slow for e.g. 450 Values in Range1 comparing every value with all 550 Values in Range2. More efficient solutions are welcome.

Here is my current unoptimized code:

```
Sub CompareProtocollTexts()

    Dim column1 As String, column2 As String, column3 As String
    Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range, c As Range, zelle, zellen

    column1 = 1 ' Column with Structure Element
    column2 = 2 ' Column with Error Code
    column3 = 3 ' Column with Error Text

    Worksheets("Table1").Select

    'first Table
    LastRow1 = Sheets("Table1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow1
        Range("F" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(Table1!R" & i & "C" & column1 & ", Table1!R" & Reihe & "C" & column2 & ", Table1!R" & Reihe & "C" & column3 & ")"
        Range("F" & i).Copy
        Range("F" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Next i

    'second Table
    LastRow2 = Sheets("Table2").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    For t = 2 To LastRow2
        Range("G" & t).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(Table2!R" & t & "C" & column1 & ", Table2!R" & Reihe & "C" & column2 & ", Table2!R" & Reihe & "C" & column3 & ")"
        Range("G" & t).Copy
        Range("G" & t).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Next t

    'now compare ranges in the new columns (F is 6; G is 7)
    Set wkTab1 = Worksheets("Table1")
    LastRowF = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowG = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

    Set range1 = wkTab1.Range("F2:F" & LastRowF)
    Set range2 = wkTab1.Range("G2:G" & LastRowF)

    For Each zellen In range1
        For Each zelle In range2
            If zellen.Value = zelle.Value And zellen.Value <> "" Then
                zellen.Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
                zellen.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
                Exit For
            Else:
                'colorize non-identical positions
                zellen.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 '(green = 4 ; yellow = 6 ; red = 3)
                'currently missing: colorize other cell (if matches F4 then colorize C4) in same line
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Definitely a use case for loading arrays to VBA and minimizing the VBA-Excel exchanges. Besides you forgot to rename all the variables (check `Reigh`).

Comment: At least you'd do it for the comparison part. After the concatenation, load the column `AM` and `AL` into VBA arrays and do the comparisons there. Collect the differing row indices in a collection. This should speed up for sure, but the bottleneck still seems to be the algorithm's complexity (O(m.n.l))

Comment: Is the difference only in the text column? I mean is it initially *sure* that the pairs (structure-element, error-code) are the same in the two tables, but only the order might be different?

Comment: Ok, this is very complex stuff for me - still learning. The difference is only in the error text. But you can have same error text in different structure elements with same error code. That's why I'm trying to check for identical elements (pairs) before checking for non-identical text. As far as I can say, the pairs are identical in the 2 tables, the order of the rows can different. It can also be that an "old" pair is missing in the new table (means: the error was fixed). Could you help me with some code?

Comment: Sure, with pleasure. But please first correct the typos in the code so that it can compile and work correctly (tested on a small test case). I'd start from there to improve it :)

Comment: Fixed above - old column AL became column F and AM became G. 
Other columns StructureElement, ErrorCode and ErrorText became just 1,2 and 3. Tested it with the upper written tables and it worked. Don't know how to add an Excel File with macros here.

Comment: My answer below, I worked on the "old" columns 9, 21 and 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code runs much faster. The basic idea is to use intensively the powerful methods built-in Excel, and there's no need for any intermediate concatenation.
Here I use `CountIfs`, which resulted in the best performance.

```
Sub CompareProtocollTexts()
    Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range, r As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   With Sheets("Table1")
        Set range1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 22), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp))
    End With
    With Sheets("Table2")
        Set range2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 22), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each r In range1.Rows
        With range2
            If Application.CountIfs(.Columns(1), r.Cells(1).Value2, _
              .Columns(13), r.Cells(13).Value2, .Columns(14), r.Cells(14).Value2) = 0 Then _
                r.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks simply good to me - no waste of time or extra resources :-) 
Will check it tomorrow and let you know how it works.

Comment: For colorizing only the non-identical cell I changed your `r.Interior.ColorIndex = 6` to `r.Cells(14).Interior.ColorIndex = 6` and it does the job. It works (nearly) perfect and is very performant. Thanks a lot!!! Nearly perfect because a few but very very long strings make problems. They are identical but I can't say why they are marked as non-identical. When you try to put the string into a search field (STRG+F) manually by copy and paste it will also not work (won't put it in) - guess it's something like >256 chars or whatever. Currently it's not critical to the programm or for my analysis.